# Hot and cold temperature regulation

Tags: temperature-control

I'd like to start regulating the temperature of my beers and meads during fermentation, and have been looking at kits like the [Mangrove Jack's Temperature Controller](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/281710787369).

However, judging by the description it can only be used either in heating or cooling mode not both at the same time.

I'm doing my brewing in a garage, which can get quite cold at night (5 degrees) but also quite hot during the day (35 degrees) as the garage door is exposed to direct sunlight.

How can I (cheaply) keep my fermenter at a steady temperature under these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept looking and came across devices like this one which permits the use of both the heating and cooling plugs at the same time:

[Inkbird ITC-308](http://www.homebrewfinds.com/2015/12/hands-on-review-inkbird-itc-308-dual-stage-temperature-controller.html)

Answer (score 2):

STC-1000 is a very common temp controller. It does require that you do the wiring, but that is fairly simple.

It works great as a temp controller for fermentation, however, you do need to check the amps if you use it in an electric brewery.

Comment: STC's are super easy to use and work like a bomb. Reliable and can be built into anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with "one-way" control by putting your fermentor in a fridge and controlling a heater.  I wrap my fermentor with a heating device then insulate it well with several towels and bungee cords.  The whole thing goes in the fridge which is just set to stay cold (40F).  The heater kicks in when the fermentor needs it.  Works well and is less taxing in the fridge compressor than trying to control the fridge in my experience.

Comment: This also works with an aquarium heater.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my garage. The days have been going up to 35, so in the morning I have soaked a towel with cold tap water and wrapped it around the carboy.  This surprisingly keeps it to between 20 and 22 Celcius.

At Night, I bought 2 of these [heat belts](http://hopdawgs.ca/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=243) (1 for each carboy) and a [dual stage temperature controller](https://www.amazon.ca/Anycontrol-AC-211-Stage-Temperature-Controller/dp/B00R66K1QE) for night time.

I will be getting a chest freezer soon and setting up my temp controller with it similar to [this build](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=231979).